# Criteria for a map of rings to induce an equivalence on K-theory?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Algebraic $K$-theory is Morita invariant, but surely it does not *detect* Morita equivalence. What are some examples of rings (or ring spectra) $R$ and $S$ that are not Morita equivalent, but nevertheless have equivalent $K$-theory spectra?

More generally, what are some conditions (necessary and/or sufficient) for an exact functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ between stable $\infty$-categories to induce an equivalence $K(\mathcal{C}) \to K(\mathcal{D})$ on $K$-theory spectra?

Comment: If $R$ is a non-zero ring such that $R \simeq R \oplus R$ as $R$-modules. Then $K(R) \simeq \ast$. The ring map $R \to 0$ induces an equivalence on $K$-theory but $R$ and 0 are not Morita equivalent.

Comment: To add to Kristian's excellent answer, an explicit example is given by the ring of column-finite matrices, ie. $C(R) = End_{R}(R^{\infty})$ where $R$ is arbitrary ($C(R)$ is sometimes called the "cone ring" of $R$).

Comment: @K.J.Moi thanks! (and thanks Piotr for the explicit example.) This feels to me close to a swindle, because such an $R$ is necessarily "infinite" in some way (if $R$ is commutative, for example, then it must be an infinite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra). Is there an example of a ring $R$ with $K(R) \simeq 0$ where $R$ is more "finite"?

Comment: If $R$ is any regular ring (say, a field), then $K(R)\rightarrow K(R[X])$ is an isomorphism, by Quillen.

Comment: @ReubenStern The $R\simeq R\oplus R$ condition is even worse than you suspect: the only commutative example is the zero ring (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number).

Comment: @PeterScholze thanks for that example; I must have forgotten about it!